# Pentaho report which contains more than 7 connections are not working in pentaho DI server

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-report-designer

I am new to pentaho. Recently i created a job which generates some report. I am using JNDI connection in the report(.prpt). If I am using more than 7 connections inside a report, it will fail to generate report but it's working smoothly with reports which has lesser connections.

Note: If i execute using spoon, it will work fine even report has more JNDI connections but my requirement is to execute job using pentaho kettle API like this -> 
https://address/pentaho-di/kettle/executeJob/?job=/home/pentaho/Test/main.kjb&level=Rowlevel

Seeking for help from pentaho experts.

Comment: you need to post the logs somewhere to work out why it's failing. I'm not aware of any limit, so doubt it's related to the 7 connection thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually due to issue in data factory.

Steps to do:

1. Stop your Pentaho DI Server if it is already running.
2. Navigate to
   server\data-integration-server\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\META-INF and
       edit the context.xml file.
3. In your jdbc/mart JNDI connection change the factory class from,
   factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" to,
   factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
4. Save and close the file.
5. Clear tomcat\work and tomcat\temp directories.
6. Restart your PDI server.
7. Execute the transformation